# Volley cancel all task when back press

Tags: android, android-volley

i am using volley and in success i am doing some task

viewPager.setAdapter(PagerAdapter);

the problem is when i press back it continues task  then it crashing  as activity is finish ..any way we can cancel it like asynctask  .like activity.isfinishing something

Answer (score 0):

If you store your requests in a request queue you can call mRequestQueue.cancelAll(this) or you can assign tags to your requests and cancel them by tag.

Comment: but then it will cancel all task which return in success . should i do this on back press .

Comment: it will cancel all tasks which are still running....i'm guessing this is what you want to do in case the activity is finised. if the activity is finished the success response will no longer be of any use

Comment: its not full finish . its under finishing mode

Comment: override the onDestroy() method and release all the resources you are using in this activity. Check if resources are null on success.